# Custom Keyboard Layout to use H J K L as ARROWS not working properly

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, xkb

I set up my keyboard layout in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` to use the keys <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd> as arrows <kbd>Left</kbd>, <kbd>Down</kbd>, <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Right</kbd> as the third and fourth shift level. mostly I followed [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/96299/mapping-superhjkl-to-arrow-keys-under-x).
The <kbd>R. Alt</kbd> is my Alternative Characters Key.

While this customization will "basically" work, I can not select text by typing it in conjunction with <kbd>Shift</kbd>. For example, I can not select the text by pressing <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, as it would do with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>. But I can jump a whole word with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

The <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd> are working exactly like the arrows in Firefox (with <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) but not on Gedit, Rhythmbox or Chrome, and possibly more...

Any ideas?
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

---

Edit:I am using a german keyboard with <kbd>AltGr</kbd>.
and the files are the fowllowing:

[link to keyboard layout](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/67b10aba7c5db1ff775e)

(hope the link works now)

Comment: Can you post the file you are currently using? I asked something similar here:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/684459/configure-caps-lock-as-altgr-to-allow-easy-arrows

Comment: i thought i set those file as public, but... well tried with the link you gave me... (I only have the layout file with me at the moment, which anyway is more relevant for you) - hope it works.

Comment: thanks the link on gist works. but where do I have to change anything now? there are lots of files in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/`. I use german layout too, but the symbols file seems weird to me. Maybe you can create a file for us, that we just have to append to the symbols file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to `xkb/types/iso9995` and edit the `"THREE_LEVEL"` type by adding

```
  preserve[Shift+LevelThree] = Shift;
```

so it looks like this

```
  partial default xkb_types "default" {

// A key type which can be used to implement
// an ISO9995-style level-three shift.

virtual_modifiers LevelThree;

type "THREE_LEVEL" {
    modifiers = Shift+LevelThree;
    map[None] = Level1;
    map[Shift] = Level2;
    map[LevelThree] = Level3;
    map[Shift+LevelThree] = Level3;
    preserve[Shift+LevelThree] = Shift;
    level_name[Level1] = "Base";
    level_name[Level2] = "Shift";
    level_name[Level3] = "Level3";
    };
};
```

Then go to your symbols file and use this format

```
    key <AC06>  { type="THREE_LEVEL", [               h,               H,            Left ]     }; 
    key <AC07>  { type="THREE_LEVEL", [               j,               J,            Down ]     }; 
    key <AC08>  { type="THREE_LEVEL", [               k,               K,              Up ]     }; 
    key <AC09>  { type="THREE_LEVEL", [               l,               L,           Right ]     };
```

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/498710/xkb-remap-arrow-keys-and-preserve-shift-behaviour-to-select-text) is a related question from which I could figure out the answer to yours.

Comment: Great! it worked. 
The only thing is that the file is called `iso9995`.

Comment: Right, my bad. Edited